# How can i test async functions using express, mongoose and nodeunit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, mongoose

How can i use [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http) for testing async? for eg: I have this in my express router which can be reached through GET /category/list

```
var getData = function (req, res) {
Category.find({}, function (err, docs) {
if (!err) {
    res.json(200, { categories: docs });
} else {
    res.json(500, { message: err });
    }
});
};
```

and in the test

```
var request  = httpMocks.createRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/category/list',
    body: {}
});
var response = httpMocks.createResponse();
getData(request, response);
console.log(response._getData());
test.done();
```

but the response does not contain the json (response comes back later after a few seconds). How can i test this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback parameter to the `getData` function which executes when Mongoose has returned the data.

```
var getData = function (req, res, cb) {
  Category.find({}, function (err, docs) {
    if (!err) {
      res.json(200, { categories: docs });
    } else {
      res.json(500, { message: err });
    }
    cb();
  });
};
```

and then do

```
var request  = httpMocks.createRequest({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/category/list',
  body: {}
});
var response = httpMocks.createResponse();
getData(request, response, function() {
  console.log(response._getData());
  test.done();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Any other way rather than adding callback because i have a lot of code that i'm writing tests now so i want to add something in the test than changing the code.

Comment: Not what I am aware of, although you're gonna start notice that you're going to need callbacks in almost every function you make either way so there's nothing wrong with adding a callback to your existing functions.

Comment: OK.

last question - my app.js has this routing for the above function

in app.js
app.use('/category/list', categories.getData);

and in routes/categories.js
var getData = function (req, res) {
....
}

Now if i add callback, express will be able to route it?